# how can I scroll component when we are in mobile response

Tags: reactjs, scroll, responsive-design

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PM2UL.jpg) According to the component specified in the image, how can I have scroll in the mobile size of the website in this component so that overflow does not occur and the responsiveness of the page is not damaged?
i want this component have scrollX and not overflowX

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaHp1.jpg)

My BestProductStore.js component:

```
import React from "react";
import TitleStore from "../../../components/Store/Title/titleStore";
import "./bestProductStore.css";
const BestProductStore = () => {
  const cards = [
    {
      img: "/nahoor home page/store page/Mihan poster.png",
      title: "تولید انواع ماست و پنیر",
      brandImg: "/nahoor home page/store page/mihan logo.png",
    },
    {
      img: "/nahoor home page/store page/Mahram poster.png",
      title: "تولید انواع ماکارونی و پاستا",
      brandImg: "/nahoor home page/store page/Mahram Logo.png",
    },
    {
      img: "/nahoor home page/store page/Zar makaron poster.png",
      title: "تولید انواع ماکارونی",
      brandImg: "/nahoor home page/store page/Zar makaron logo.png",
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div className="bestProductStore-container">
      <div>
        <TitleStore title="برترین تولید کنندگان" />
      </div>
      <div className="bestProductStore-main">
        {cards.map((card) => {
          return (
            <div
              className="bestProductStore-cards"
              style={{ width: "100%", height: "80%"}}
            >
              <img
                width="100%"
                height="100%"
                src={card.img}
                alt=""
              />
              <div className="bestProductStore-cardsContent" >
                <div width="100%">
                  <img src={card.brandImg}  />
                </div>
                <div  style={{ width:"100% " , textAlign: "left"}}><p className="bestProductStore-paragraph" width="100%">{card.title}</p></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BestProductStore;
```

and My BestProductStore.css component:

```
.bestProductStore-container {
  /* display: flex; */
  margin-top: 36px;
 white-space: nowrap
}
.bestProductStore-main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 24px;
}
.bestProductStore-cards{
position: relative;
border-radius: 4px;
overflow: hidden;

}
.bestProductStore-cardsContent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top:8%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24%;
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  padding:0 8px
}
.bestProductStore-paragraph::after{
content: ">";
margin-right: 16px;
}
.bestProductStore-cardsContent img{
  width:80%
}
@media (max-width: 1600px){
  .bestProductStore-cardsContent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
    
  }
  .bestProductStore-paragraph{
    font-size:0.8rem
  }
  .bestProductStore-cardsContent img{
    width:80%
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1300px) {

  .bestProductStore-cardsContent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items: center;
 
  }
  .bestProductStore-paragraph{
    font-size:0.6rem;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .bestProductStore-cardsContent img{
    width:80%;
    
  }

}
@media (max-width:768px) {

  .bestProductStore-main {
    min-width: 800px;
  }

}
```

please help me thankyou

Answer (score 0):

I did much trying that **.bestProductStore-main** to have entire width and scroll-x, but the page gets the scroll. Of course in your CSS, you should write @media like this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {

  .bestProductStore-main {
    min-width: 800px;
  }

}
```